# Splitting strings using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have multiple strings like :

```
a = 'avg yearly income 25,07,708.33 '
b = 'current balance 1,25,000.00 in cash\n'
c = 'target savings 50,00,000.00 within next five years 1,000,000.00 '
```

I'm trying to split them into chunks of strings of texts and strings of numbers with sample output like :

```
aa = [('avg yearly income', '25,07,708.33')]
bb = [('current balance', '1,25,000.00', 'in cash')]
cc = [('target savings', '50,00,000.00', 'within next five years', '1,000,000.00')]
```

I'm using the following code :

```
import re
b = b.replace("\n","")
aa = re.findall(r'(.*)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d){1,2})', a)
bb = re.findall(r'(.*)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d){1,2})(.*)\s+', b)
cc = re.findall(r'(.*)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d){1,2})(.*)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{1,2})?)', c)
```

I'm getting following output :

```
aa = [('avg yearly income', '25,07,708.3')]
bb = [('current balance', '1,25,000.0', '0 in')]
cc = [('target savings', '50,00,000.0', '0 within next five years', '1,000,000.00')]
```

What's wrong with the pattern of regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `re.findall`, you can use `re.split` to split the strings on a space bounded by a letter and a digit:

```
import re
d = ['avg yearly income 25,07,708.33 ', 'current balance 1,25,000.00 in cash\n', 'target savings 50,00,000.00 within next five years 1,000,000.00 ']
final_results = [re.split('(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s(?=[a-zA-Z])', i) for i in d]
new_results = [[i.rstrip() for i in b] for b in final_results]
```

Output:

```
[['avg yearly income', '25,07,708.33'], ['current balance', '1,25,000.00', 'in cash'], ['target savings', '50,00,000.00', 'within next five years', '1,000,000.00']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` with the ptrn `r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\w)|(?<=\w)\s+(?=\d)'`

```
>>> ptrn = r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\w)|(?<=\w)\s+(?=\d)'
>>> re.split(ptrn, a)
['avg yearly income', '25,07,708.33 ']
>>> re.split(ptrn, b)
['current balance', '1,25,000.00', 'in cash\n']
>>> re.split(ptrn, c)
['target savings', '50,00,000.00', 'within next five years', '1,000,000.00 ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.split()`; This example uses your original regexp and it works fine:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{1,2}))')
>>> r.split('avg yearly income 25,07,708.33 ')
['avg yearly income ', '25,07,708.33', ' ']
>>> r.split('current balance 1,25,000.00 in cash\n')
['current balance ', '1,25,000.00', ' in cash\n']
>>> r.split('target savings 50,00,000.00 within next five years 1,000,000.00 ')
['target savings ', '50,00,000.00', ' within next five years ', '1,000,000.00', ' ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split as said in above answers.

```
import re
a = 'avg yearly income 25,07,708.33 '
b = 'current balance 1,25,000.00 in cash\n'
c = 'target savings 50,00,000.00 within next five years 1,000,000.00 '

aa = re.split(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{1,2}))', a)
bb = re.split(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{1,2}))', b)
cc = re.split(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{1,2}))', c)

print(aa)
print(bb)
print(cc)
```

You can get output like

```
['avg yearly income ', '25,07,708.33', ' ']
['current balance ', '1,25,000.00', ' in cash\n']
['target savings ', '50,00,000.00', ' within next five years ', '1,000,000.00', ' ']
```